# manipulate string in splunk

Tags: logging, splunk

I have a multi line event in Splunk that looks like this:

```
{"log":"text 1\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-09-12T10:06:27.318327863Z"}
{"log":"text 2\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-09-12T10:06:28.318327863Z"}
{"log":"text 3\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-09-12T10:06:29.318327863Z"}
```

splunk shows log as

```
log: text 1
```

and ignores other lines. I need a field that says for example:

```
log_sample: text 1
            text 2
            text 3
```

I'm not a Splunk admin so I can not change the config of Splunk. What I need is kind of a regex function so that I can manipulate the event. I tried this pipeline:

```
...| rex max_match=0 field=_raw "(?<lineData>zone.*?mark=(\},|\}\s+\]))" | mvexpand lineData
```

but it was not working (I found it on the internet)

Comment: It is rather preferable to use a a json parser that a regex on this kind of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of why one should not copy code from the Internet without understanding what it does.  The regular expression used in the `rex` command is for a completely different target string.  You need to modify the regex to match your data.

Try this, instead.

```
| rex max_match=0 "log\\\":\\\"(?<text>[^\\\"]+)" | mvexpand text
```

Comment: thank you it's working but you must add "text" to end of command

Comment: Fixed for posterity